# Can i use file system in ubuntu without installing (running via USB)

Tags: installation, usb, filesystem

I want to use the file system like all drive from the hard drive without installing Ubuntu only running via USB.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean running Ubuntu from the USB flash-drive, then Yes you can. It will work OK.

But if you mean install Ubuntu on a flash-drive, then you can create a persistence USB.  You can create it by using  Live USB creator.

For more information click [Here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent)

keep in mind that it might be a little slow

Comment: Yes and to be honest there are other distributions more adapted for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you run Ubuntu from a USB memory stick, you get the full functionality of Ubuntu – including access to local filesystems. Because I have Ubuntu on my keychain, I've been able to help Windows users recover files on more than one occasion.